# Hide back faces in 3D View?

Tags: modeling, interface, workflow, 3d-view, normals

How do you hide back faces so that you only see faces when its normal is facing the camera? When exporting it for use in a game, the face is rendered in only the direction of its normal, so this would be useful to have something similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Blender 2.8+

This depends on your viewport shading mode (**Solid**, **Material Preview**, and **Rendered**) and render engine (**Eevee**, **Workbench**, and **Cycles**).

### *Solid* viewport shading mode:

Regardless of your current choice of render engine, this is easily set in **Solid** mode. Click the dropdown arrow to open the **Viewport Shading** panel and tick the **Backface Culling** checkbox.

[image: Solid viewport shading]

### *Material Preview* and *Rendered* viewport shading modes:

#### Eevee

Backface culling is enabled on a per-material basis in Eevee. Open the **Material** tab and, under **Options**, tick the **Backface Culling** checkbox.

[image: Eevee render engine]

#### Workbench

Go to the **Render Properties** (camera icon) tab and, under **Settings**, tick the **Backface Culling** checkbox.

[image: Workbench render engine]

#### Cycles

There is no checkbox because Cycles lacks backface culling as a specific feature. You will instead need to use a combination of three shader nodes to achieve the same result on a per-material basis. Downstream of any existing nodes (immediately before the **Material Output** node), insert a **Mix Shader** node with a **Transparent BSDF** node connected to the lower **Shader** input and a **Geometry** node's **Backfacing** output connected to the **Fac** input.

[image: Node setup]

Answer (score 8):

You find the *Backface Culling* option in the *Properties Panel* <kbd>N</kbd> shading section while in *Object Mode*.

The effect with a default cube and one partially removed face.

[image]

When renderer is set to *Game Engine* the *Backface Culling* option is also available in the material's settings.

[image]

Comment: I have posted an alternate updated answer for Blender 2.8.

Comment: Sorry about the downvote, but it made the difference in bumping the up-to-date answer to the top...